# How to correctly link a static library in C++?

Tags: c++, gcc, compilation, linker-errors

When trying to compile my project, I am getting `undefined reference to 'reflex::Input::file_get(char*, unsigned long long)'` error.

I exactly know where that function is. It is in a file called `input.cpp` I have tried my best to link it. But I'm unable. Here is the steps I did:

- Compiled `input.cpp` to `input.o`. (`g++ -isystem..\RE-flex\include -c ..\RE-flex\lib\*.cpp`).
- Created `libreflex.a` from `input.o`. (`ar -rcs .\bin\libreflex.a *.o`).
- Built the project using `libreflex.a`. (`g++ -o myproj.exe -isystem..\RE-flex\include -L.\bin -lreflex myproj.cpp -g -std=c++20`).

But still I am getting linker errors. I can't find any solution to this specific case. Please correct me where I gone wrong.

Comment: change order `myproj.cpp -lreflex`

Comment: @KamilCuk  How should I know these? Further reading links?